# Identification of structural parameters in a linear model (treatment effect context)

Tags: regression, least-squares, linear-model, treatment-effect, identifiability

Suppose that we have $N$ observations indexed by $i=1,...,N$.

The observations are partitioned in three groups indexed by $g=1, 2,3$.

Here, we consider potential outcomes $Y_{ig}^0,Y_{ig}^1,Y_{ig}^2$.

That is, we are considering three potential treatment status,

and $Y_{ig}^0$: untreated potential outcome of an individual $i$ who is included in the group $g$, $Y_{ig}^1$: potential treated outcome of $i$ in $g$ who took the treatment of level one, and $Y_{ig}^2$: potential treated outcome of $i$ in $g$ who took the treatment of level two.

In this situation, suppose that the data generating process is as follows:

$$Y_{ig}^0=v_{ig}$$
$$Y_{ig}^1=\alpha_0D_{i0}+\alpha_1D_{i1}+\alpha_2D_{i2}+Y_{ig}^0$$
$$Y_{ig}^2=\beta_0D_{i0}+\beta_1D_{i1}+\beta_2D_{i2}+Y_{ig}^0,$$
where $v_{ig}$ is the usual error term and $D_{ig}$ is one if an individual $i$ is in a group $g$ and zero otherwise.

As we know, we can identify the structural parameters $\alpha_1$ and $\beta_2$ like below:

$\begin{align} Y_{ig}=&Y_{ig}^0+(Y_{ig}^1-Y_{ig}^0)D_{i1}+(Y_{ig}^2-Y_{ig}^0)D_{i2} \\
=&v_{ig}+(\alpha_0D_{i0}+\alpha_1D_{i1}+\alpha_2D_{i2})D_{i1}+(\beta_0D_{i0}+\beta_1D_{i1}+\beta_2D_{i2})D_{i2}
 \\
=&\alpha_1D_{i1}+\beta_2D_{i2}+v_{ig}\end{align},$

where $Y_{ig}$ is the observed (or realized) outcome.

Thus, we can estimate $\alpha_1$ and $\beta_2$ by using LSE (regression $Y_{ig}$ on $D_{i1}$ and $D_{i2}$).

However, I want to know other structural parameters, $\alpha_0, \alpha_2, \beta_0, \beta_1$, as well.

Although I tried to what all I know, I was not able to come up with how to identify the parameters.

So, how can I identify the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You could add another column in your data matrix as a categorical variable which would be the treatment with 3 levels.
Then you could fit a model with the interaction between.

Let $x_{i,j}$ be the treatment for an individual $i$ with levels ${0, 1, 2}$.
We treat $x_{i,0}$ as a reference category and so it is simply covered by the intercept term $\alpha_0$

$x_{i,j}$ for $j=1,2$ are indicators which are one if individual $i$ received treatment $j$

For a model with just the categorical variable as a predictor we have:
$Y_i = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1*x_{i,1} + \alpha_2*x_{i,2} + \epsilon_i$

In this case $\alpha_1$ corresponds to the difference in the intercept between treatment 0 and treatment 1 and $\epsilon$ is the error term.

With another continuous predictor where we want to see the interaction between the treatment and the predictor say $z_i$ we fit a model of the form, where $\epsilon$ is our error term:
$Y_i = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1*x_{i,1} + \alpha_2*x_{i,2} + \beta_1*z_i + \beta_2*(z_i*x_{i,1}) + \beta_3*(z_i*x_{i,2}) + \epsilon_i$

This gives three regression lines which differ according to the treatment:

For treatment 0: $Y_i^0 = \alpha_0 + \beta_1*z_i + \epsilon_i$

For treatment 1: $Y_i^1 = (\alpha_0 + \alpha_1) + (\beta_1 + \beta_2)*z_i + \epsilon_i$

For treatment 2: $Y_i^2 = (\alpha_0 + \alpha_2) + (\beta_1 + \beta_3)*z_i + \epsilon_i$

We then think of $\beta_2$ and $\beta_3$ as the difference in the slope of the regression line of going from treatment 0 to treatment 1 and 2 respectively.

In `R` this would be implemented something like

```
lm1 <- lm(y ~ treatment + z + z:treatment)
```

Comment: The last three equations are just for conditional expectations, which is a different concept from the potential outcomes. My question is related to the structural parameters in the data generating process, so the starting point of your answer imposing the linear model of the "observed" outcome seems awkward.